# Lista encadeada - [Error] storage size of 'minhaLista' isn't known

Tags: c

Estou tendo problemas ao desenvolver uma lista encadeada, por favor me ajudem.
Toda vez que tento compilar aparece o erro na linha 7 [Error] storage size of 'minhaLista' isn't known

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já mudei a estrutura de lugar, fucei em tudo mas continuar tendo problema

**Arquivo main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lista.h"

void main () {

    struct ListaSimplesEnc minhaLista;

    criarLista(&minhaLista);

    int valor, op;

    while( 1 ){

        printf( "1 - Inserir elemento no inicio\n" );
        printf( "2 - Inserir elemento em ordem (so se a lista estiver ordenada)\n" );
        printf( "3 - Remover elemento no inicio\n" );
        printf( "4 - Remover elemento\n" );
        printf( "5 - Mostrar lista\n" );
        printf( "6 - Sair\n" );
        printf( "Opcao? " );
        scanf( "%d", &op );

        switch( op ){

            case 1: // inserir elemento no inicio

                printf( "Valor? " );
                scanf( "%d", &valor );
                inserirIni(&minhaLista, valor);
                break;
            case 2: // inserir elemento ordenado
                printf( "Valor? " );
                scanf( "%d", &valor );
                inserirOrd(&minhaLista, valor);
                break;
            case 3: // remover o primeiro
                break;
            case 4: // remover determinado elemento
                break;
            case 5: //  mostrar lista
                if (estaVazia(&minhaLista)) {
                    printf("Lista vazia");
                }
                else {
                    mostrarLista(&minhaLista);
                }
                break;
            case 6: // abandonar o programa
                exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

**Arquivo lista.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lista.h"

struct Nodo {

    int info;
    struct Nodo *prox;

};

struct ListaSimplesEnc {

    struct Nodo *prim;

};

void criarLista (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList) {

    pList -> prim = NULL;

}

void mostrarLista (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList){

    struct Nodo *p;

    for (p = pList -> prim; p != NULL; p = p->prox) {

        printf("%d\t", p->info);

    }

    printf("\n");

}

void inserirIni (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList, int v){
    struct Nodo *novo;
    novo = (struct Nodo*) malloc (sizeof (struct Nodo));
    novo -> info = v;
    novo -> prox = pList -> prim;
    pList -> prim = novo;
}

void removerIni (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList){

    struct Nodo *pAux = pList -> prim;
    pList -> prim = pList -> prim -> prox;
    free(pAux);

}

void inserirOrd (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList, int v){
    struct Nodo *novo;
    novo = (struct Nodo*) malloc (sizeof (struct Nodo));
    novo -> info = v;

    struct Nodo *pAtu, *pAnt;

    pAnt = NULL;
    pAtu = pList -> prim;

    while ( pAtu != NULL && pAtu->info < v){

        pAnt = pAtu;
        pAtu = pAtu -> prox;

    }

    novo -> prox = pAtu -> prox;
    pAnt -> prox = novo;
}

int estaVazia(struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList) {

    return (pList->prim == NULL);

}
```

**lista.h**

```
struct ListaSimplesEnc minhaLista;

void criarLista (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList);

void mostrarLista (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList);

void inserirIni (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList, int v);

void removerIni (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList);

void inserirOrd (struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList, int v);

int estaVazia(struct ListaSimplesEnc *pList);
```

Comment: você precisar dar detalhes, ninguém vai conseguir adivinhar os problemas...

Comment: @zentrunix Toda vez que tento compilar aparece o erro "Erro [warming] 'struct ListaSimlesEnc' declared inside parameter list".

já mudei a estrutura de lugar, fucei em tudo mas continuar tendo problema

Comment: você tem que colocar as explicações e os detalhes (por. exemplo, qual linha está dando erro ? qual fonte está dando erro ?) na pergunta, e não nos comentários

Comment: Declare suas structs no arquivo .h

Comment: não é assim que funciona este site...você faz o programa, e quando tiver uma dificuldade específica você pergunta aqui sobre essa dificuldade específica...aí normalmente vai aparecer alguém para ajudar...mas tem que ser um problema específico, porque este não é um site de mentoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa declarar as estruturas nos .h e não nos .c.

Exemplo:

Arquivo lista.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lista.h"

// struct Nodo
// {
//   int info;
//   struct Nodo *prox;
// };

// struct ListaSimplesEnc
// {
//   struct Nodo *prim;
// };

struct ListaSimplesEnc minhaLista;

// ...
// ...
```

Arquivo lista.h

```
struct Nodo
{
  int info;
  struct Nodo *prox;
};

struct ListaSimplesEnc
{
  struct Nodo *prim;
};

extern struct ListaSimplesEnc minhaLista;

// ...
```

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo, fiz a alteração e funcionou!

Comment: então por favor, marque minha resposta como aceita

Answer (score 0):

Declare suas structs no arquivo .h

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou :)